# Is the Ricci tensor zero in black holes because of the Kasner solution?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, curvature

Is the Ricci tensor zero in black holes because of the [Kasner solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kasner_metric)? I'm asking this to help resolve an uncertainty of mine as to which of two cosmological models (Aguirre & Gratton's "steady state eternal inflation" and Poplawski's "cosmology with torsion") is more plausible.

Comment: What does the Kasner metric have to do with black holes? Also, $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ for *any* vacuum solution of the EFE's, not only Kesner's. Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: The Schwarzschild and Kerr black holes are (perhaps surprisingly) vacuum solutions i.e. the stress-energy tensor is zero everywhere except at the singularity where it is undefined. That's why the Ricci tensor is zero everywhere except at the singularity where it is undefined.

Comment: And how would that tell you anything about those other two cosmological models? Mainly when you don't know why the Ricci tensor is zero in vacuum spacetime

Comment: @ Bob Bee.  What I'd hoped it might tell me is whether the relation between space and time changes in Poplawski's "universe within a BH", as it seems able to do in the Krasner solution (which I believe had been marked as "related" to my ?).  I'd naively figured that Poplawski's cosmology resulted in a scaling down of both space and time, whose relation to each other would remain the same.  What I've been able to find out about the Kerr metric, maybe more appropriate, shows it to be well beyond my comprehension.

Comment: I've found a way to make a comparison between the Poplawski and the Aguirre and Gratton cosmologies that may be more appropriate to my lack of education, and may want to ask questions about it in a week or two.  I'm flagging a moderator to request deletion of the question at hand.  I apologize for the time spent on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $R_{\mu \nu} = 0$ is just Einstein's equations in vacuum.

Can be seen as follows:

$$ R_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2} R g_{\mu \nu} = 8 \pi G T_{\mu \nu} = 0 $$

multiply (and contract) both parts by $g^{\mu \nu}$:

$$ R - \frac{1}{2} R \cdot 4 = R - 2 R = - R = 0 $$
$$ R_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0 \cdot g_{\mu \nu} = R_{\mu \nu} = 0; $$
$$R_{\mu \nu} = 0.$$